# Connect to Azure Database from SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms-2012

I am connecting to an Azure hosted SQL Server using SSMS and am getting an error I can't track down. This happens when I open the connection and try to select a database to use or try to refresh the database list.

Reference to database and/or server name in 'msdb.dbo.syspolicy_configuration' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

[image]

Comment: I would try to install newest version 17.5 (SSMS is now standalone and free) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Answer (score 0):

For the best experience with Azure SQL Database please download for free the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Please download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).

The latest version of SSMS is compatible also with SQL Server 2008 and later.

SSMS 2012 is not compatible with many changes and improvements Azure SQL Database has received the last 6 years.

Comment: I would have thought it rather the database ENGINE version than SSMS ? Let me try the SSMS install (latest)

Comment: yep: as I suspected this is database ENGINE problem. Installing the latest SSMS did not yield success and by the way the same error is thrown in my UI application (not when using SSMS) which proves a compatibility in the data being queried. My best bet would be to re-configure the "compatibility level" directly in Azure (IF SUCH SETTING EXISTS)

Comment: Yes. You can change compatibility level on Azure SQL DB.